# viper-mode changes <delete> key

Tags: emacs, viper, viper-mode

I want to use the `<delete>` key (C-d, I think) for forward-deletion in viper-mode.

Before starting viper-mode, `<delete>` works correctly. In viper-mode, `<delete>` jumps to the buffer's last line.

I have added `(setq viper-ex-style-editing nil)`  to .viper and `<backspace>` works in all modes.

Comment: Since you're using viper-mode we need more information.  Do you want this to be bound in insertion mode?  Or command mode?  Both?  What level of viper user are you (1-5)?

Comment: I'm using viper on level 5. I want to use `<delete>` in both insertion and command mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define-key viper-vi-basic-map "\C-d" 'viper-delete-char)
(define-key viper-insert-basic-map "\C-d" 'viper-delete-char)
```

Now, that uses the `viper-delete-char` command to be consistent with `viper`.  If you want the regular emacs deletion behavior, use `delete-char` instead.

`viper` is implemented using a bunch of different keymaps, and figuring out which ones to modify is tricky.  The easiest way (usually) is to just look at the source code.  So you could start with <kbd>M-x find-library viper</kbd>.  *Note:* Most keymaps are actually defined in the library `viper-cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

The \ key will switch back to Emacs mode for a single key stroke, so you can do what you are seeking with "\<delete>" without making any changes or adding any code to your .emacs file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's what you do.

(1) In viper mode, use `C-h k` to find out what `<delete>` is bound to.  Just in case you want it attached to some other key.

(2) In some other mode, use `C-h k` to find out what the name of the function is that does what you want.  I think it's `delete-forward` but don't trust me, check.  RMS has an annoying tendency to rename things.

(3) Back in a viper-mode buffer use `M-x local-set-key` to set  to what you want.  Try it.

(4) If you're happy add this code to your .emacs

```
(defun fix-del-key-in-viper-mode ()
  (define-key viper-mode-map "<delete>" your-desired-function))
(add-hook viper-mode-hooks fix-del-key-in-viper-mode)
```

Warning, you may have to mess about with this a bit as I haven't tested it.  In particular make sure it's really `viper-mode-map` and not something else, as the naming conventino isn't consistently followed.

Comment: Ack, I can't set <delete> in viper-mode. I can set other keys (like <insert>) to `delete-char` and they work. <delete> refuses to change.